# Generating all IP addresses in the IPv4 range using C

Tags: c, loops, ip

How would I go about doing this in C?
I would like to generate all possible IPv4 IP addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255
I tried four for-loops but it didn't work. I new to C and programming and I would be interested in how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe if you show the loops we can explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Post what you tried and the problem you found in your code.

Comment: Hint: you're really just asking for a list of all unsigned 32-bit numbers.

Comment: @CarlNorum Which is a lot of numbers. If it's going to be printed to the screen, OP may want to choose a small font.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment an IP address in a loop? \[C\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257273/how-to-increment-an-ip-address-in-a-loop-c)

Answer (score 2):

This will run for a lot of time (due to `printf` printing to the console). I suggest you to test it using a smaller value for `MAX_COMPONENT` (5~6).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_COMPONENT 255

int main( void )
{
    for ( int c1 = 0; c1 <= MAX_COMPONENT; ++c1 )
        for ( int c2 = 0; c2 <= MAX_COMPONENT; ++c2 )
            for ( int c3 = 0; c3 <= MAX_COMPONENT; ++c3 )
                for ( int c4 = 0; c4 <= MAX_COMPONENT; ++c4 )
                    printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", c1, c2, c3, c4 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be relevant that I assumed C99 compliance. In C89 you have to move the declarations of `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4` out of the for loops and place them at the beginning of main's body. :-)