# Replacing one number in a text and cloning it with a new value

Tags: linux, shell, replace

I need to change some numbers in a rule, like 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.x, where x is a value between 3-254. So'll have multiple lines, one with the value 192.168.1.2, other with the value 192.168.1.3, and so on.
Well, I've no clue how to do that.
If someone know of a program or some way to do using a script in linux, please let me know.

Comment: Didn;t understand if you need to change 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.x or 192.168.1.x to 192.168.1.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I increment an IP address represented as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505676/how-do-i-increment-an-ip-address-represented-as-a-string)

Comment: This is barely a duplicate because this question is asking for something scriptable, and the other question is for C++. Still, this question is so unclear that is deserves closing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU sed`. Simply replace `X` with the value you wish to use.

```
sed 's/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}\)[0-9]\{1,3\}/\1X/g' file.txt
```

Test:

```
echo "192.168.1.4" | sed 's/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}\)[0-9]\{1,3\}/\1X/g'
```

Result:

```
192.168.1.X
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using `awk` to avoid the hairy regex route (nothing wrong with regexes in general, but sometimes they can make your eyes bleed...):

```
awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s.%s.x\n",$1,$2,$3}'
```